# Turn off translator cache

Tags: symfony, caching, localization

I'm trying turn off translator cache by this way:

*app/config/config.yml*

```
    services:
        translator.default:
            class:  %translator.class%
            arguments: [ @service_container, @translator.selector, {}, { cache_dir: null, debug: %kernel.debug% }, @?session ]
```

The cached code in cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php should be:

```
    protected function getTranslator_DefaultService()
    {
        $this->services['translator.default'] = $instance = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator($this, new \Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector(), array('translation.loader.php' => 'php', 'translation.loader.yml' => 'yml', 'translation.loader.xliff' => 'xliff'), array('cache_dir' => NULL, 'debug' => true), $this->get('session'));

        ... resources ...

        return $instance;
    }
```

But i get followed code:

```
    protected function getTranslator_DefaultService()
    {
        return $this->services['translator.default'] = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator($this, new \Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector(), array('translation.loader.db' => 'db', 'translation.loader.php' => 'php', 'translation.loader.yml' => 'yml', 'translation.loader.xliff' => 'xliff'), array('cache_dir' => NULL, 'debug' => true), $this->get('session'));
    }
```

So translator resources is empty.

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same problem..

Comment: Nope, we have changed framework to Silex.

Answer (score -6):

One way to do this is:

Edit `symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Translation/Translator.php` and add a method:

```
public function setOption($option, $value)
{
    $this->options[$option] = $value;
}
```

In your `AppKernel.php` override a method:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    $this->container->get('translator')->setOption('cache_dir', null);
}
```

Comment: I have to aggree with this on the other commentor. On each composer update you will loose your changes